# What's JSC_MULTIPLE_VAR_DEF?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I spent half an hour finding the answer to this question. Posting it here along with an answer, hoping it'll save someone half an hour.

When compiling this code

```
"use strict";
/**
 * These are the flower and the instrument used in the code below.
 */
var flower, instrument;
```

the Closure Compiler gives us this warning

```
JSC_MULTIPLE_VAR_DEF: declaration of multiple variables with shared type information at line 6 character 0
var flower, instrument;
^
```

What does this vague warning mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Closure Compiler allows you to define type information for variables, inside comments. Like so:

```
/**
 * The amount of beats in each minute.
 * @type {number}
 */
var bpm = 89;
```

Even though the comment in the example doesn't contain any type information, the compiler complains that if such type information existed, it would only be used for the first variable (*flower*) and not for the second one (*instrument*.)

Answer (score 5):

You should file a bug for this:
http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/list

It should only complain if you are using @type. Even then it isn't clear to me this is appropriate.  It seems like I should be able to do this:

```
/** @type {string} */
var a,b,c;  // all strings
```

Comment: This has irritated me for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a bug of Closure Compiler. It assumes you use @type in the comment starting with /**, even you haven't.

The warning can be dismissed by changing the comment tag from /** to /* . E.g.

```
"use strict";
/*
 * These are the flower and the instrument used in the code below.
 */
var flower, instrument;
```